# using curl to cronjob a url

Tags: php, curl, ssh, cron, mediatemple

I have an application on php-Codeigniter hosted on MediaTemple and I want to have a cron job runing a controller, the support told me to use CURL  I tried using without any succes, example:

```
curl http://mydomain.com/admin/action/get
```

My controller inserts some information to a  database, the curl doesn't display error but the inserts are not happening only when I run the controller directly on the browser works. no auth  is required.

any idea?

thanks

Comment: You can always try wget instead of curl.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide more information about what's happening before people can really help you.  Please see this [helpful guide to asking questions](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Some starting points:

1. What happens when you run that command from command line?
2. What happens when you go to the controller URL in a Web browser?
3. What exactly does your "not any success" consist of?  What indications of success are you looking for and what are you observing?
4. Does your controller require authentication?  If so, you will need to tell `curl` how to supply it.  If not, be aware that you're allowing this process to be actuated by anyone on the Internet, which may facilitate denial-of-service attacks or other security issues.

Comment: My controller inserts some information to a  databse, the curl doesnt display error but the inserts are no happening only when i run the controller direclty on the browser works. no auth  is required.

Comment: `curl` doesn't display an error; does it display the output produced by the controller?  (If there is any, that is.  If there isn't, you should probably add some temporarily for debugging.)  Like, if you do `curl http://www.google.com/`, you'll see that `curl` should show you the content of the Web page retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a cronactivator.php file, and point your cronjob to this file. No CURL needed.

```
<?php 
//for php4 use fopen
$html_data = file_get_contents('http://www.yoursite.com/framework/controller/action', 'r');
echo "DONE!";
exit;

?>
```

Comment: That assumes `allow_url_fopen` is on, which is usually off. Use PHP's CURL instead....oh, oops, you ended up using CURL anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

@seth - I'm not on a linux box so can't really test this out, but your issue is either **curl itself is not installed** or **curl needs certain specific switches to work**.

If you still want it to work, first get it to work via the server's SSH (use Putty on Windows) or alternatively you can write a script to test it out;

```
<?php
    $code=system('curl --help');
    echo '<br><br> Exit Code: '.$code;
?>
```

Not that if it writes any other error code than 0, you have issues with CURL.

---

On the other hand, you can use `wget` instead. It is more supported on Linux than CURL (afaik). Though I'm a big fan of CURL, it just so happens that `wget` is more popular for this kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

Or... you could just write a PHP script that is intended to run on the CLI and assign the cron task directly to the php file:

```
php -f /path/to/my/file.php
```

Heres [some information](https://www.php.net/cli) on using PHP on the CLI. There are [ways to do this](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CI_on_the_command_line/) with CodeIgniter.

That said, there's a way to find out for sure if the request is going anywhere. (besides saving the output of the request) CodeIgniter is equipped with excellent logging methods. You could set your `$config['log_threshold']` in <kbd>application/config/config.php</kbd> to something like `3`. Run the request in both a browser, and then once in the CLI. Then look in your <kbd>application/logs</kbd> folder for log file for the current day. Find within the file the URL that you're requesting. There should be two places where it is logged. If there's less than the number of requests you made in the log file, then you know that something is wrong with CURL. Otherwise, you know something is wrong with the app.